# Is it safe to call jcuda.driver.JCudaDriver/cuInit multiple times in a program?

Tags: cuda, jcuda

I'm using a dynamic language (Clojure) to create CUDA contexts in a interactive development way using JCuda. Often I will call an initializer that includes the call to `jcuda.driver.JCudaDriver/cuInit`. Is it safe to call cuInit multiple times? In addition, is there something like a destroy method for cuInit? I ask since its possible for an error code `CUDA_ERROR_DEINITIALIZED` to be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question, yes it is probably safe to call `cuInit` multiple times. I haven't noticed any side effects from doing so.

Note, however, that `cuInit` only triggers one-time initialisation processes inside the API. It doesn't do anything with devices, or contexts and it definitely can't return CUDA_ERROR_DEINITIALIZED. Doing the steps you would do *after* calling `cuInit` in an application (ie. creating a context) would have real implications - doing so creates a new context each time you call it and resource exhaustion will occur if contexts are not actively destroyed. There is no equivalent deinitialisation call for the API. I guess the intention is that once intialised, the runtime API is expected to stay in that state until an application terminates.